# Possible to determine, if Object 1 is referenced by an Object 2 (root) through arbitrary levels of other object references?

Tags: java, reflection, reference

Is it possible to determine, if Object 'O' is referenced by an Object 'R' (root) through arbitrary levels of other object references?

Example:

```
public class Car {
    public Driver driver;
}

public class Driver {
    public License license;
}

public class License {
    public ID id;
}

public class ID {
}
```

With this setup, the references are 'Car -> Driver -> License -> ID'.

Now, when I have in instance of 'Car' (C) and an instance of 'ID' (I), I want to determine, if I is referenced by C (not directly, but through any levels of other references).

One solution is to use reflection recursively and "search for" the instance 'ID' with the search root beeing the 'Car'. If the algorithm starts at 'Car' and "goes down the reference tree" and it finds the 'ID' instance, that means 'ID' is indirectly referenced by 'Car'. (Just a recursively algorithm like in XML serializer, visiting the object hierarchy).

The drawback of this solution is, it takes rather long to find an answer, because in the worst case, the whole object hierarchiy (from 'Car' on must be visited (and the object tree can be complex, of course)).

My concrete question is now: Is it possible to do it the other way around, from 'ID' to the root 'Car', like with parent classes, but with concrete object references?

A pseudo code would look like this:

```
parent = ID.getParent()
while ( parent != Car ) {
    parent = parent.getParent()
    if ( parent == null )
        break;
}
```

(Please note that the pseudo code works on objects and references, not parent classes).

I'm not sure if Java Reflection is able to do this, or if there is no such child->parent reference information, when no class member references are set manually.

My goal is the following:

A have a complex domain model with lots of classes. If one class property anywhere in those classes gets written (e.g. 'car.setDriver(...)), I must serialize that whole domain model ("save the document"). To detect a property change (note that I can't use AOP in my context) I use my own PropertyChangeSupport in those setter-methods of the domain classes and push the PropertyChangeEvents to an EventBus. Now I can detect changes and save the domain model accordingly.

One problem remains: I must determine, if the property change belongs to a cartain object instance, which is referenced by my root object (the root object of the domain model).

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: can't you keep track of the parent of each object using PropertyChangeSupport?

Comment: The basic answer is no.  There is no way to distinguish a reference that occurred through `A ->B ->C ->D` from one that occurred through `A ->E ->F ->D`.  You can, at some expense, get the call stack and see if the calling sequence is of one flavor vs another, but that doesn't tell you what precise references were used to reach the current point.

Comment: To solve your problem the usual approach is to have each object contain a "parent" pointer that links it back to its immediate "owner".

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. @dev no I can't because there are no parent-references.

Comment: @hotlicks It's not possible, because the system must work for arbitrary domain models / class trees. Your second comment could be the right answer to the question - sometimes, there is just no way to do it.

Comment: @It'sLeto but you could have a custom PropertyChangeSupport implementation or a custom listener where you establish the parent relationship. e.g: as soon as the setter method is called you set the parent of the argument to the setter method. parent could be passed when u instantiate the custom PropertyChangeSupport/listener implementation